# Why isn't there a quantum number associated with the Lorentz boost?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, special-relativity

It is a re-post of [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/397830/where-isnt-there-a-quantum-number-associated-with-the-lorentz-boost) since there is no answer.

I am doing problem 3.2 of Schwartz's QFT and figured out all previous questions, where we identified the conserved current of Lorentz transformation:
$$
K^{\mu\nu\alpha}= x^\mu T^{\alpha\nu}-x^\nu T^{\alpha\mu}
$$

and the corresponding conserved quantity of boost:
$$
Q^i=\left(t\mathbf{p}-E\mathbf{x}_{CM}\right)^i
$$

In the last question, he is asking

> Show that $\frac{d Q^i}{dt}=0$ is consistent with $i\frac{\partial Q^i}{\partial t}=\left[Q^i,H\right]$. Thus ... they do not provide invariants for the equation of motion ...

However, I am a little confused.

1) What does "being consistent with" mean? Is there a way possible to introduce some inconsistency, like a contradiction or something?

2) In second equation, things are operators, right? But previously we all work with numbers. How do we jump from numbers to operators?

3) Does "invariants for the equation of motion" mean a symmetry? Surely
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}Q^i}{\mathrm{d}t}=\frac{\partial Q^i}{\partial t}+\frac{\partial Q^i}{\partial p^i}\frac{\mathrm{d} p^i}{\mathrm{d} t}+\cdots
$$
and the LHS equals zero does not imply $\frac{\partial Q^i}{\partial t}=0$. Since a symmetry must commute with the Hamiltonian, thus $Q^i$ does not provide a symmetry. Is this argument answer the question?

Sorry I am quite confused about the question. Do appreciate any answers!

Following I attached the whole question:

> Show that $\frac{d Q^i}{dt}=0$ is consistent with $i\frac{\partial Q^i}{\partial t}=\left[Q^i,H\right]$. Thus, although these charges are conserved, they do not provide invariants for the equation of motion. This is one way to understand why particles have spin, corresponding to representations of the rotation group, and not additional quantum numbers associated with boosts.

Comment: I fear Matt assumes well-meaning agility beyond an introductory  textbook here...  He is sticking to the equations of motion / Noether conservation law, PBs of the classical theory, and wants you to observe the vanishing of the time derivative of the boost "charge" is but the dynamical equation of the momentum "charge", the equation of motion, and not a new fixed entity. Look at Weinberg's book for more detail.  He writes a commutator since that's manifestly what the relation upgrades to upon quantization ("consistent"). Give him some flexibility and slop and you might see his point....

Comment: @CosmasZachos ok... thanks!